# Splitting the html string to a list

Tags: python

This is my string:

```
'<.tag> xxxxx<./tag> <.tag>'
```

I want to append it to a list as:

```
x=['<.tag>','xxxx','<./tag>','<.tag>']
```

Comment: Have you tried parsers like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

Comment: If you don't want to use BeautifulSoup, you could use a regex pattern

Comment: Yeah , i have tried using Beautiful soup , the problem is that the it may contain a comment tag like <!--article....> , which beautiful soup cannot read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awesoon's right, use a parser.

*However*, this will do it:

```
def f(x):
    lst = []
    rec = ""
    for i in x:
        if i == "<":
            if rec != "":
                lst.append(rec)
            rec = ""
        rec += i
        if i == ">":
            lst.append(rec)
            rec = ""
    return lst
```

It essentially records everything between a "<" and a ">" and adds it to a list. It also records gaps between all ">" and "<" so that things like 'xxxx' will be recorded

Answer (score 3):

use  [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) for this purpose

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result

```
In [1]: a='<.tag> xxxxx<./tag> <.tag>'

In [2]: import re
In [4]: re.findall(r'<[^>]+>|\w+',a)
Out[4]: ['<.tag>', 'xxxxx', '<./tag>', '<.tag>']

In [5]: re.findall(r'<[^>]+>|[^<]+',a)
Out[5]: ['<.tag>', ' xxxxx', '<./tag>', ' ', '<.tag>']

In [17]: [i.strip() for i in re.findall(r'<[^>]+>|[^<]+',a) if not i.isspace()]
Out[17]: ['<.tag>', 'xxxxx', '<./tag>', '<.tag>']
```